# VS Code React Component Ctrl Click disable quick view and open in new tab instead?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Somehow I could not manage to figure this out for hours now...

How can I disable this quick view window(see below for picture) when I ctrl or cmd + left click on a component(react file) and instead open the file in new tab?

[image]
I have the followings in my settings.json already.

```
{
  "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
  "workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false
}
```

[image]

PS: have also tried closing the vscode and reopen it. Restart even my mac and also tried shutting down the router and plugging out the internal cable. still does not work...

Comment: A "preview editor" is something different entirely: it's basically a tab that isn't obliged to stay open (e.g., if you close VSCode and reopen it, the tab won't be there). As for the actual problem, alas, it still seems to be an open bug: see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37816